# How many permutations of this alphanumerical string are possible under these conditions?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The string is in the format:

$N_1 N_2 L_1 L_2$

Under the following conditions:

$N_1$ and $N_2$ can be numbers 0-9, and $L_1$ and $L_2$ can be letters A-Z.

Initially, I thought it would just be $(99 x 26^2)-26=66,898$ but I have a feeling I'm missing something.

Thanks

Comment: You are missing two things: the amount  of possible numbers is 100 instead of 99 (maybe you forgot 00?) and if you don't want permutations of the string repeated, you should divide by two the number of combinations of letters  (you don't want AB and BA at the same time as one is a permutation of the other)

Comment: You've just made me realise my question was wrong slightly - AB and BA is allowed. Because of how I was evaluating the permutations in my head I somehow reached the conclusion that there could be two instances of AA...ZZ etc. A bit silly really. Edited to remove the duplicates statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the permutations of the resulting string should all be unique, then:

- Numbers can be selected in $10\cdot 9$ ways
- Letters can be selected in $26\cdot 25$ ways

Thus there are $10\cdot 9\cdot 26\cdot 25 = 58500$ possible combinations.

**EDIT**

If there are no restrictions for permutations, then there are $10^2 26^2$ possible ways to construct the string.

There are 4 possibilities (in brackets is the number of unique permutations of the resulting string):

- Numbers are equal, letters are different ($\frac{4!}{2!} = 12$)
- Numbers are equal, letters are equal ($\frac{4!}{2!2!} = 6$)
- Numbers are different, letters are equal($\frac{4!}{2!} = 12$)
- Numbers are different, letters are different($4! = 24$)

Comment: "Duplicate letters are not allowed". That doesn't mean duplicate numbers aren't allowed

Comment: The question stated, that all permutations of the resulting string should be unique, thus the strings 00_ _, 11_ _, ..., 99_ _ are also not allowed.

Comment: Just to aid in my understanding, assuming that the condition about the duplicates still applied, why would 00,11...99 be excluded? My statement was intended to mean that permutations of the entire string must be unique, therefore, AFAIK, 00AB and 00YG, for example, would be permitted.

Comment: @Phizzy Yup. The permutations of string abcd are, amongs others: abcd, bacd. If we say, that a=b=1, c=A, d=B (11AB), then these permutations are not unique.